# Reading Linux environment variables in PHP pool configuration files

Tags: php, environment-variables, fpm

I've set an environment variable named `DISPLAY_ERRORS` with the value `on`.

I'm trying to use this environment variable in `php-fpm.d/www.conf`, however I can't figure out the right syntax. Here is what I've tried:

**1:**

```
[www]
php_flag[display_errors] = $DISPLAY_ERRORS
```

**2:**

```
[www]
php_flag[display_errors] = $(DISPLAY_ERRORS)
```

**3:**

```
[www]
php_flag[display_errors] = ${DISPLAY_ERRORS}
```

**4:**

```
[www]
php_flag[display_errors] = "${DISPLAY_ERRORS}"
```

None of the above seems to work. In all cases I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: [/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:17] error while parsing 'php_flag[display_errors]' : invalid boolean value
```

**NOTE** - I know that "on" is not a boolean value, however `php_flag[display_errors] = on` works fine so I'm assuming the problem is in how I try go get the variable's value.

Comment: #1 is the format to use. I wonder if incoming environment variables are only available to the `env` array. Let's experiment: in `www.conf`, try `env[foo] = $DISPLAY_ERRORS` then in PHP after reload try `echo getenv('foo');` Also make sure `clean_env = no` in your FPM conf. What's the result of that?

Comment: Are you settings the env var in your user session, and expecting fpm to see that?

Comment: @bishop - when I do what you wrote I'm getting the value I set in the `$DISPLAY_ERRORS` environment variable.

Comment: @Maerlyn - I'm setting the env var using Docker environment variables. This works fine inside PHP code files, however not inside PHP config files.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot use env variables like that, but you should be able to access them via `$_ENV` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen incoming environment variables used on any line other than `env[]` assignments. While that may be possible, based on the result of your experiment (as outlined in the OP comments), it appears that PHP FPM can only access incoming environment variables during `env[]` assignment ... not `php_flag` or any of the other directives.